PowerApps dynamic form with scrollbar
I need to build a form in PowerApps where users can dynamically add multiple input rows by clicking a button.
Also, if the content exceeds the page size, I want the form to be scrollable.
Is this possible in PowerApps? If so, what controls or methods should I use to achieve this?
Thanks!
Exemple of expected

Forms are meant for handling single records, Form can display many or all fields in that record. Update one or more fields in a single record  and save those changes back to the underlying data source.
In your case what is + Add a Subscription  button doing? where is it adding the record? Fields in your screenshot like Offer, Fix fee, total etc. seems like input fields. And I assume you add them to database on Add button.
To display added records you can use Gallery, Gallery display only a few fields from each record to show several records at a time, on a small screen. You can scroll through records in a data source, and select a specific record to view details in other screen.
